# Less vstemplate for vs2012

Tags: less, visual-studio-2012

How to create a new less file template for vs2012 ?

Just like what [Web Workbench](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench/getting-started) does.

When you install this extension, you will see 3 extra file templates for LESS SASS coffeeJS.

However, I don't want to install this extension.

Because I more like to use another extension, but it misses this feature I like to have.

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 1):

1) Create a less file.
2) File->Export Template
3) Choose Item Template
4) Check your less file from the list.
5) Do couple more next and done.

Comment: I think it should work, but somehow I still can't make it work.